# Where this is a web hosting control panel?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[Override template homedir on FreeNAS 11.3 joined in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/1023705/override-template-homedir-on-freenas-11-3-joined-in-active-directory)

FreeNAS/TrueNAS is an enterprise grade storage system. This is not even near as a web hosting panel. Sorry for the honesty but whoever closed this should be back to the basics and learn the difference on things like: cPanel, Plesk, Webmin to things like: TrueNAS, FreeNAS, NAS4Free, Nexenta.

I was looking around if there's any update in my question and just seen this. And yes, I'm a little offended by this closure. It's just like I don't know what I'm asking or is it if I'm not aware of basic sysadmin things.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: This would be a more compelling question without the commentary, ie if there was actually a question in the body of the post.

Comment: The question was how to achieve the override. I tried just to be cool and said what I've looked by myself.

Comment: Sure seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, not sure what I was thinking there.  I've reopened it.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :)